# mmenu: Override tapped button background-color

Tags: javascript, css, mmenu

I used mmenu as a jQuery plugin 5.6.1. Is there a way to replace the background color when a menu button is tapped. I tried all focus and hover styles in the css files but none changes the color.

Tested with mmenu: v5.6.1
Device: Samsung Galaxy S4
Browser: Firefox, Chrome

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a button is tapped, its state while tapped is active.  You can change its background colour using the `selector:state` format in CSS, doing something like this

```
menu-item:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Have a play with the snippet below

```css
button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  transition: linear all 0.2s;
  outline: none;
}

.menu-item:active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: linear all 0.2s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu-item">
This is the menu-item button
</button>
```